# Why does Angular throw no provider for ' ' when it does exist in providers list?

Tags: angular

I have the following injectable service

```
import { ConfigService } from './app-config.service';
import { Injectable, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AppInsights } from 'applicationinsights-js';

@Injectable()
export class AppInsightsService {
  appInsightsInstrumentationKey: string;

  private config: Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.IConfig = {
    instrumentationKey: this.appInsightsInstrumentationKey
  }

   constructor (private configService: ConfigService){
     this.configService = configService;

     this.appInsightsInstrumentationKey = 
     configService.config.appInsightsInstumentationKey;

     if (!AppInsights.config) {
       AppInsights.downloadAndSetup(this.config);
     }
  }

  logPageView(name?: string, url?: string, properties?: any, measurements?: any, duration?: number) {
    AppInsights.trackPageView(name, url, properties, measurements, duration);
  }

  logEvent(name: string, properties?: any, measurements?: any) {
    AppInsights.trackEvent(name, properties, measurements);
  }
}
```

The ConfigService is in the providers list in the app.module (in fact it is being injected into other classes just fine)

```
     providers: [
        LoaderService,
        ConfigService,
        {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: loadConfig,
          deps: [ConfigService],
          multi: true
        },
        DaterangepickerConfig,
        TriggerEventAssignmentComponent,
        TimelineSummaryComponent,
        AlternateTemplateService,
        SelectedTriggerService,
        RouteHistoryService,
        AppInsightsService
      ],
```

When injecting the config service into the AppInsightsService however I get the error:

> Error: No provider for ConfigService! (AppInsightsService -> ConfigService)

The AppInsightsService is injected into the app.component constructor.

Am I not able to inject into an injectable or is there something else happening here?

Update: I get this with anything that I try to add to the Constructor of this AppInsightsService. I have tried things like 'Http' And I get the same error saying no provider for HTTP. So this has something to do with how the AppInsightsSerivce is used in angular and when is being loaded. I suspect its being loaded before the App.Module has does it's work?

Comment: Where did you declare `configService` to access `this.configService`? In AppInsightsService?

Comment: Ah, a line got removed. Updated